# Dynamically create SharePoint page without List from C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

We have a MVC application which holds different ranges of products for our customer.
They require us to create a new page and populate it using a specific page template on the SharePoint site with certain fields which are entered onto the product within the Application.

What i am looking to see is if there is anyway we can publish these fields direct from the external application to the new page using the template, check it in and publish it without the need to create a list to hold the data fields? they are requesting everything is done automatically without any manual interaction what so ever.

I have carried out some research and everything suggests the fields need to be held in a list first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint almost everything is stored in a list (even pages, but it is called document library). So that would be the best way.

Create a content type which contains the fields the products needs. Create a page layout (explained for example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-create-a-page-layout-in-sharepoint)) which uses the specific content type. Then in your page layout make the fields visible (change the layout with sharepoint designer). 
And then, for each product, just add a new page to the pages library using the new page layout/content type. Adding the page could be done via client api from the external application.

Comment: Thing is we are so tight with Governance and Change control the Team Leader now wants us to Edit the Web Controls to manipulate the data, so what he wants is to use the same Layout that's been in place but instead of the user manually entering fields he now wants them pulled from the list and populated. This then means that the old files already created can be updated by new products and new pages will following the same layout as before so everything is consistent. hes now tasked me with finding out where the info is stored and how to manipulate it ... any ideas